# How to pronounce C++11 in English?

Tags: pronunciation, programming

How to pronounce C++11 in English, "c plus plus one one" or "c plus plus eleven"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it's not a standard English word, there's no standard pronunciation. You'd need to check with whoever made it up, such as (possibly) the [C++ Standards Committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/), if you're referring to [ISO/IEC 14882:2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11).

Comment: It's eleven, plain and simple. Nobody refers to the year 11 as the year one-one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Only if you recognise that it's a (sort of) sequential number. On the other hand, phone numbers (say, 555-1234) aren't typically read as "five million five hundred and fifty-one million, two hundred and thirty-four". They are read digit-by-digit. The year 2018 is variously pronounced "twenty-eighteen" or "two thousand eighteen" etc. Even short sequences such as the [555-timer](https://theamphour.com/how-to-say-555-timer/) are often pronounced digit-by-digit. **There is no context-free convention about the pronunciation of numbers**.

Comment: In this case, the context (C++) lets one know to pronounce it as a year: "eleven".

Comment: @xmllmx Please [edit] the post to provide adequate context—where do you encounter this term, and why are references for this term inadequate for your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "See plus plus eleven".

I happen to be a C++ developer (and an English lover, for some reason)

The number is just the year of standardization. when a new C++ standard is standardized by ISO, that C++ standard is colloquially called "C++ (num)"

C++11 is the C++ standard that was approved by ISO in 2011, replacing the older standard of C++03.